# How to uninstall gtsam library c++

Tags: c++, cmake

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have installed gtsam 4 library from : https://bitbucket.org/gtborg/gtsam.git and since I am facing troubles with compilation I want to uninstall it and link to a local version. The problem is that `make uninstall` does not exist. Is there a way to remove it or at least make the local version be used instead of it.
In CmakeLists.txt I have `include_directories` and `link_directories` pointing to the local version but still the gtsam which is installed is the one that is used.

I found  `install_manifest.txt` file in build directory. As I read [here](https://gkiagia.wordpress.com/2009/12/24/introducing-cmake_install/) it contains all the files to be installed. However. I noticed that most of the files are `.h` and some are `.cmake` I do not know if just deleting those files will fix the problem or is going to mess it up.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/233493/how-to-uninstall-gtsam-library-c++/) by [Abdallah sobehy](https://answers.ros.org/users/26124/abdallah-sobehy/) on ROS Answers with karma: 33 on 2016-05-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When you install headers and libraries to a system include directory such as `/usr/include` and `/usr/lib`, the installed includes/libs will often be accessible because something else is used in that directory and it is therefore on the compilers/linkers include paths. If it is there before your local version, these files overshadow the local version. In principle, this should be managable somehow, but I couldn't solve this in the past, so I removed the installed files using the `install manifest.txt`:

```
rm `cat install_manifest.txt`
```

You might move them somewhere instead, just to be safe

```
mv -v `cat install_manifest.txt` /tmp
```

Though you could re-install them by `make install` anyway.

---

Originally posted by [Felix Endres](https://answers.ros.org/users/113/felix-endres/) with karma: 6468 on 2016-05-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0